# IOS Swift Amazon S3 transfer utility- nil is not compatible with expected argument type nsurl

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3

[image]

I am new to Amazon S3 and was trying the example found in GitHub https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample/Swift
But when i try to build and run i get the below error message

**nil is not compatible with expected argument type nsurl**

below is the code where i am having issue with.

```
let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.defaultS3TransferUtility()

    transferUtility.downloadToURL(nil, bucket: S3BucketName, key: S3DownloadKeyName, expression: expression, completionHander: completionHandler).continueWithBlock { (task) -> AnyObject! in
        if let error = task.error {
            NSLog("Error: %@",error.localizedDescription);
            self.statusLabel.text = "Failed"
        }
        if let exception = task.exception {
            NSLog("Exception: %@",exception.description);
            self.statusLabel.text = "Failed"
        }
        if let _ = task.result {
            self.statusLabel.text = "Starting Download"
            NSLog("Download Starting!")
            // Do something with uploadTask.
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

kindly let me how to fix the issue
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I've used `AWSS3TransferUtility` (yet), but it looks like you need to be passing an `NSURL` instance that points to where you want the file downloaded to. There's an example of [how to do this (in obj-c) on the AWS developer blog](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx283AGGIL76PKP/Amazon-S3-Transfer-Utility-for-iOS).

Comment: You're welcome! If an answer solved your problem, please consider marking it as accepted (checkmark on the left side).